# What methods are available to typeset Chinese？

Tags: languages, characters, cjk

What is the main way to support Chinese currently？

For example, this is one way:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ctex} % <=====================================0
\begin{document}
我和你
\end{document}
```

I want to know some better method and am wondering what is now available.

Comment: I've tried to clarify your question as it was a little difficult to follow. Could you check that it is what you meant to ask? If not, you can roll back my edit.

Comment: In what way is the method you mentioned suboptimal?

Answer (score 2):

In general，you can use the class maintenanced by CTEX forum, such as ctexart,ctexbook, if the XeLaTeX is used as the compiler, you can use the xeCJK package which is convenient for selection of the fonts installed in your system.

Comment: What's available with lualatex?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with  lualatex :(

Comment: Now I must say , usepackage ctex can solve  almost all problem about chinese